# What can cause form buttons to fail in firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, forms

I have some form buttons

```
&lt;input type="button" onclick="send_away('700302','update_item','0',2)" value="Change Quantity"&gt;
```

and they are calling the functions below: (different buttons call different functions from this script, which is embedded in the HTML file.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function send_away(item_c,request_c,change_item_c,quantity_c){

form_c.item.value = item_c;
form_c.request.value = request_c;
form_c.change_item.value = change_item_c;
form_c.quantity.value = quantity_c;
form_c.submit();
} 

//sends the form later

function later(){
address.incoming_address.value = 'l';
address.submit();
}

function address_now(){
form_c.incoming_address.value = 'n';
form_c.submit();
}

function remove_item(item_num){
form_c.removal.value = item_num;
form_c.submit();
}
</script>
```

The problem is, not one of these buttons works in firefox. They all work in every other browser I've tried.

Has anyone run into this kind of problem / know what I could be doing wrong? I've stared at it for a while and can't see anything, other than that my HTML doesn't validate very well, I don't have nearly time to fix all the validation problems though.

You can see the effect at http://www.terra-cotta-pendants.com/ - click a product and add it to cart - the buttons are on the cart page.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

add id="form_c" to your form and use document.getElementById('form_c') instead of just form_c

another option would be to access the form by using document.forms.form_c, but I have always preferred using id's